# Configure rust for helix editor on windows 11

Tags: windows, rust, rustup, helix-editor

When running `hx --health rust` I do not have any check passing for rust.

How can I configure rust to work with [Helix editor](https://helix-editor.com/) on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

On a machine using Windows 11 and having the command line installer [scoop](https://scoop.sh/#/) installed, I have managed to configure rust for [Helix](https://helix-editor.com/) easily following the next steps:

1. Install rustup-gnu (not just rustup):

   ```
   scoop install main/rustup-gnu
   ```
2. Install llvm:

   ```
   scoop install main/llvm
   ```
3. Check Helix health for rust lang:

   ```
   hx --health rust
   ```
4. Check the ouput looks like:

   ```
   Configured language server: rust-analyzer
   Binary for language server: C:\Users\<username>\scoop\apps\rustup-gnu\current\.cargo\bin\rust-analyzer.exe
   Configured debug adapter: lldb-vscode
   Binary for debug adapter: C:\Users\<username>\scoop\apps\llvm\current\bin\lldb-vscode.exe
   Highlight queries: ✓
   Textobject queries: ✓
   Indent queries: ✓
   ```